# Assign OnClickListener dynamically to custom layouts

Tags: android, onclicklistener

In Android, I have created an interface with 2 main columns. Both columns have custom objects that must act as buttons. These custom objects are based on a simple custom class (ButtonItem) that has 2 textviews. Also I have a layout that contains a LinearLayout (vertical) with the two TextViews inside. In the main view, I fill both columns with and adapter and example content using the custom class and placeholder texts, and the result is that the columns have "buttons" with 2 independent text lines. The problem is to add an OnClickListeners to these objects. My idea was to add some attribute for each ButtonItem to assign an action when clicked, but until now I've had no success.

This is how the columns are filled (updated)

```
public class TicketSaleActivity extends Activity {

    private ListView lv;
    private LinearLayout ll;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ticket_sale_layout);

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.buttonList);
        ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);

        ArrayList<ButtonItem> buttonItemList = new ArrayList<>();

        ButtonItem buttonItem1 = new ButtonItem();
        buttonItem1.setUpperText("1€");
        buttonItem1.setBottomText("Billete a Narnia");
        ButtonItem buttonItem2 = new ButtonItem();
        buttonItem2.setUpperText("1.5€");
        buttonItem2.setBottomText("BILLETE A CANGAS DE ONIS");
        ButtonItem buttonItem3 = new ButtonItem();
        buttonItem3.setUpperText("1.25€");
        buttonItem3.setBottomText("Billete a Narnia");
        ButtonItem buttonItem4 = new ButtonItem();
        buttonItem4.setUpperText("2€");
        buttonItem4.setBottomText("BILLETE A CALASPARRA");

        buttonItemList.add(buttonItem1);
        buttonItemList.add(buttonItem2);
        buttonItemList.add(buttonItem3);
        buttonItemList.add(buttonItem4);
        buttonItemList.add(buttonItem1);

        ButtonItemAdapter buttonItemAdapter = new ButtonItemAdapter(this, buttonItemList);
        lv.setAdapter(buttonItemAdapter);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.i(TicketSaleActivity.class.getSimpleName(),"Clicked");
        }
    });


    for (int i=0;i<buttonItemList.size();i++)
    {
        View item = buttonItemAdapter.getView(i, null, null);
        ll.addView(item);

    }
    }
}
```

Custom class:

```
public class ButtonItem{

    private String upperText;
    private String bottomText;


    public String getUpperText() {
        return upperText;
    }

    public void setUpperText(String upperText) {
        this.upperText = upperText;
    }

    public String getBottomText() {
        return bottomText;
    }

    public void setBottomText(String bottomText) {
        this.bottomText = bottomText;
    }

}
```

Adapter

```
public class ButtonItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList<ButtonItem> buttonItemList;
    Context context;

    public ButtonItemAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ButtonItem> buttonList)
    {
        this.context=context;
        this.buttonItemList=buttonList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return buttonItemList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return buttonItemList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if(convertView==null)
        {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.button_list_item,parent, false);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.upperText = convertView.findViewById(R.id.buttonList_upperText);
            viewHolder.bottomText = convertView.findViewById(R.id.buttonList_bottomText);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);//almacenamos los elementos en la vista para reutilizarlos
        }
        else{
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.upperText.setText(buttonItemList.get(position).getUpperText());
        viewHolder.bottomText.setText(buttonItemList.get(position).getBottomText());
        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder{
        TextView upperText;
        TextView bottomText;
    }
}
```

button_list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        style="@style/list_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/buttonList_upperText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="12€"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/buttonList_bottomText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="2.5"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:minLines="2"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/buttonList_upperText" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

styles/list_button

```
<style name="list_button" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
        <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical|center_horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
        <item name="android:shadowColor">#000000</item>
        <item name="android:shadowDx">0</item>
        <item name="android:shadowDy">0</item>
        <item name="android:layout_margin">0.5dp</item>
        <item name="android:shadowRadius">0.1</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">20dip</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/default_button</item>        
        <item name="android:padding">2dp</item>
    </style>
```

Update: added ticket_sale_layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:background="@android:color/darker_gray">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

        </LinearLayout>

        <ListView
            android:id="@id/buttonList"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FFF"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout2"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/sellButton"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout3"
        tools:background="@android:color/darker_gray">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FFF"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FFF"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:text="TextView" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sellButton"
        style="@style/sell_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:text="@string/btn_sell"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either bind click listener within your adapter's `getView` method, or use [OnItemClickListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener) on your `AdapterView`:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

In order to receive callback in `onItemClick`, you should not have any clickable or focusable views in the item views. So try removing `@style/list_button` from the item XML layout, or replace it with other styles.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but seems I can't put them to work. The second solution seems the correct for me, but seems it's not working:
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.i(TicketSaleActivity.class.getSimpleName(),"Clicked");
            }
        });

Comment: Can you please post your `button_list_item` layout XML? Just making sure there's no focusable or clickable attributes in your views if you want `setOnItemClickListener` to work.

Comment: I hope your `@style/list_button` doesn't contain clickable attribute, otherwise it looks normal to me. Could you describe what is not working? Is it only the clicking issue?

Comment: Added @style/list_button. There is no clickable attribute as you can see. I want each "button" to do some action. Writing someting in the log could be a good start ^^. Right now any button is working, and for work I mean write in the log on click. and yeah, it's the only issue I have right now. Maybe I have to re-do all from scratch. Any suggestions to achieve this? And thanks for your time!

Comment: I see, so the clicking is not working you say? The code looks good, it should work. Maybe try removing `R.id.linearLayout` from your XML, and remove all other click listeners in the for loop?

Comment: Listers are removed from loop. I'll update the code to what it is now.

Comment: Weird, how are your views laid out in `ticket_sale_layout`?

Comment: Looks fine to me, are you sure that it's not printing to the log? Or if you try to test with a `Toast` instead of `Log`?

Comment: It's not printing and also tested with `Toast`, same result: nothing. I don't know what's happening but it's frustrating.

Comment: Ah found the problem: either remove `style="@style/list_button"` from your list item XML, or `parent="@android:style/Widget.Button"` from your style. Widget.Button style has `clickable="true"`, and that's why onItemClick isn't working.